# Filter duplicated objects in a Objects List

Tags: java, list, object, filter, duplicates

I have a problem with a list of object in my Java code. 
This object is populated with the following fields :

-name 
-lastname
-birthdate
-car accident date

Now, this list could countain some object with same values (name,lastname,birthdate)

For example :

Luke skywalker 09/10/1970 10/10/2008

Luke skywalker 09/10/1970 10/10/2009

my goal is to remove the duplicated user and add in a new list only the one with the latest car accident for each user.

In the previous example :

Luke skywalker 09/10/1970 10/10/2009

Do you guys have any idea?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share us your attempts, what have you tried so far. And meanwhile have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: have a look into java 8 streams and filter functionality. This should help you solve this in less code possible.

Answer (score 0):

If you let your user class implement `Comparable` then you could use a `SortedSet`:

```
class User implements Comparable<User> {
    // fields, constructor, methods etc...

    @Override
    public void compareTo(User other) {
        // assuming carAccidentDate is comparable
        return carAccidentDate.compareTo(other.carAccidentDate);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return /* true if name, lastname and birthdate are equal */
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return /* hash code of name, lastname and birthdate */
    }
}
```

I omitted the equals and hashCode implementation for simplicity, but they are also *required* for this to work.

Then simply create your `SortedSet` from the existing `List`, I use `TreeSet`:

```
Set<User> latestAccidentsUser = new TreeSet<>(users);
```

Answer (score 0):

For this question, we have 2 requirements.

Remove duplications.

Keep the lastest car accident.

For requirement 1: 
We have HashSet to remove duplication. In order to do that, we have to override equals() and hashcode(), since the default ones are based on the object memory location, while this problem is based on values(name, Lastname, birthdate).

For requirement 2: 
First, sort the Users in descending order based on the accident date. And we will have the lastest car accident in the front among the duplicates. And for duplicates will not be added into HashSet since the user has already existed.

The code is as follows:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

class User {
    String name;
    String lastname;
    String birthdate;
    String carAccidentDate;

    public User(String name,
            String lastname,
            String birthdate,
            String carAccidentDate){
        this.name = name;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.birthdate = birthdate;
        this.carAccidentDate = carAccidentDate;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (this == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (other == null || getClass() != other.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        User o = (User) other;
        return o.name.equals(name) && o.lastname.equals(lastname)
                && o.birthdate.equals(birthdate);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(name, lastname, birthdate);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.join(",", name,lastname,birthdate,carAccidentDate);
    }

    public static void main(String input[]) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

        User[] users = new User[]{
                new User("Luke", "skywalker", "09/10/1970", "10/10/2008"),
                new User("Luke", "skywalker", "09/10/1970", "10/10/2009")
        };

        Arrays.sort(users, (B, A) -> {
            try {
                return dateFormat.parse(A.carAccidentDate).compareTo(dateFormat.parse(B.carAccidentDate));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return 0;
        });

        Set<User> userSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(users));

        for(User u: userSet){
            System.out.println(u.toString());
        }
    }
}
```